# Текстовый формат для выборки данных из объекта javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть объект 
data;
И нужно через текстовый формат обращаться в его свойствам. 
Например

> "Клуб %Название% был основан в %Год% году. Цвет гостевой формы был
>   %Форма.Гостевая.Цвет%";

```
data = {
    Название: 'Динамо'
    Год: 1956
    Форма: {
        Гостевая: {
            Цвет: 'Синий'
        },
        Домашняя: {
            Цвет: 'Белый'   
        }
    }
};
```

Есть ли какие то инструменты для подобной работы? Аналог шаблонизатора только для небольших строк максимально быстрый?

Comment: Шаблонные строки не подходят? ```str = `Клуб ${data.Название} был основан в ${data.Год} году. Цвет гостевой формы был ${data.Форма.Гостевая.Цвет}`; ```

Comment: А как её вызвать для обычной строки? Без использования `?